# Tooltip for comment flags gives an option that cannot be done

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, tooltips, spelling

Just a short while ago, we got a non-answer on Arqade.  Which then got a spam comment from the same 1-rep user.  So, I was planning on flagging it as spam.

However, when you actually click on the flag button, you get:
[image]

The tooltip for hovering over the comment flag button, though, says, "flag this comment as unconstructive, offensive, or spam".

[image]

I seem to be missing a spam option, or there seems to be a small disconnect between what the tooltip says, and what you can actually do with them.

Since I don't believe I've ever seen the option to flag a comment as spam, on any site, might I suggest a small tooltip update?

Comment: Or an option to flag as spam, that would be good too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out. I have changed the tooltip to be more generic. It now says:

> Flag this comment

And clicking it will open up your flagging options.

This will be live in the next production build (meta: > `rev 2014.9.26.2606`, q&a: > `rev 2014.9.26.1893`).

Comment: Ahh you're right @CareBear. Sorry, I assumed this question was identical to another I fixed. I'll adjust this now.

Comment: Updated, thanks for pointing that out @CareBear!

Comment: Why not making it consistent with post flag, e.g. "flag this comment for serious problems or moderator attention"?

Comment: @ShadowWizard good point, I've updated it and it will change in the next build.