# Is there a habit to downvote new users by default?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, new-users

Continuing a rather dated [Downvoting of new user questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3515/downvoting-of-new-user-questions), I wonder whether meta SE has a habit to downvote new users. Every single question of mine got downvoted, sometimes with a reason, sometimes without. I deleted them so that I won't get down to a zero score. But, in this very question, I do ***not assume*** that there is such a habit, nor do I assume the absence of it.

My question is also ***not*** about why I got downvoted; I can critisize each single user of the community using roughly the same wording that they eloquently used to critisize me, so, I'm ***not*** interested in the ***why*** arguments (except for this very post).

Instead, let me ask this: has there been any new user on Meta SE in the past 3 years such that any of the first 3 questions have a positive score as of now? If your answer is "yes", please provide a link to the corresponding user profile.

The 3 years are given to set *some* definition on which users count as "new" (of course, the opinions on that may differ, and you may disagree). You could take also 3 months instead if you feel more comfortable with this definition of a "new user".

Comment: No, it's not a habit. And yes, some users get upvotes. It all depends **what** you ask, **where** you ask, and **how** you ask. Each can affect the voting patterns. [Link to user with three first questions having positive score](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/437611/blue)

Comment: 75% of the questions I asked within my first year here have a positive score, and they invited me to become a moderator within that same year. Does that count?

Comment: @Tinkeringbell Your first questions count, not your first year.

Comment: As can be seen [by such search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a369802%20is%3aq), her [first question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307173/reputation-tab-displaying-weird-wrong-dates) has score of 4 now, and as can be seen in its [timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/307173/timeline), it got four upvotes in its very first day.

Comment: @ShadowWizard ... but a duplicate (which is fair enough).

Comment: @user49915 since you're leaking rep here, maybe better come and discuss this [in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta).

Comment: I can't help but feel that there's a very distinct attempt to push an agenda with this question.  It doesn't really feel like it was asked to get an opposing answer.  Nevertheless, [my first answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/165946), and [my first question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/211379).  To my knowledge, I don't have any deleted questions, although I may have some deleted answers from question deletions.  Not sure.

Comment: @fbueckert It's not within the last 3 years, I'm afraid...

Comment: And that timeframe has been refuted.  Had been by the time my comment was made.  I'm showing an example of beyond that, showing the incorrect premise this question used.

Comment: @fbueckert The question has no incorrect premises. Your example has not been asked for.

Comment: It's just because most of new users won't bother understanding how SE works, thus making their first posts bad enough to be downvoted. However, you aren't a new user. You have been on TeX SE for a few years before....

Comment: @GetAnswerWizard but not on meta.

Comment: @user49915: "*The question has no incorrect premises.*" 3 years is an arbitrary timeframe given without any foundation, any specified reason for it. As such, it serves no purpose and I deem it to be "incorrect".

Comment: @NicolBolas I view 3 years as a time frame to define a "new user". You may disagree if you wish so, but I don't think the exact time frame is very relevant as long as it is fixed *somehow*. Question edited.

Comment: @user49915: There's no need for a timeframe. Bad questions don't get better with age. If a user was new when they posted the question, that's all that matters.

Comment: @NicolBolas But downvoted questions may (or may not) get upvoted over time, depending on who is active. Moreover, the regulations of the site change. So, some time frame is needed.

Comment: @user49915: "*But downvoted questions may (or may not) get upvoted over time*" They may also get *downvoted* over time. "*Moreover, the regulations of the site change.*" Generally speaking, site regulations have become more strict, not more lax.

Comment: @user49915: As for the specifics of your question, here is a list of new users whose initial questions didn't get downvoted. https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/504311/akari https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/485537/kousha https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/504415/greedoid https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/485537/kousha https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/513483/barrosy It took me 5 minutes to find them. Yes, most of them haven't asked 3 questions, but this clearly debunks your idea that people are downvoting posts from new users because they are new.

Comment: @NicolBolas What would you wish to debunk? I think I clearly stated the contrary of you think in "*I do not assume that there is such a habit, nor do I assume the absence of it*".

Comment: All my Qs on MSE have positive scores, including my very first one (+26). The only exception is one Q I asked with a score of 0.  I have no negative scoring Qs. They’ve all been asked in the last 3 years (starting June 2016).

Comment: Just to push back on this ownership thing: yes, it is your post.  It is, however, collaboratively edited to help make things better.  Ownership plays no stake and is a red herring when it comes to things like vandalizing your own question.

Answer (score 10):

> Instead, let me ask this: has there been any new user in the past 3 years such that any of the first 3 questions got a positive score in the long run? If your answer is "yes", provide a link to the corresponding user profile.

According to [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1029477/new-users-whose-first-three-questions-have-a-positive-score), seven in the last six months.

[image]

Of course, SEDE doesn't include information about deleted questions, so these results might be inaccurate, but only a ♦ moderator can verify that.

Comment: Fair enough. Though, the query also returns old new users; you could add a year constraint somewhere, perhaps.

Comment: What do you mean 'old new users'? The second column is when they created their Meta Stack Exchange account. They will have been around for longer on other sites in the network, sure.

Comment: If you scroll down, you find users from 2009.

Comment: I would have done that if the query would take a very long time to execute. Right now, it doesn't :)

Comment: The OP says "the past 3 years", so, though you do solve the problem, the query could have been a bit more precise. :-)

Comment: @user49915, for [networkengineering.se], that query results in dozens of users over the past three years.

Comment: @RonMaupin I don't think we discuss Network Engineering, do we? My point: you could have made the query slightly more precise, although there is no obligation to do it.

Comment: @user49915 Well which site _are_ we discussing? Meta Stack Exchange?

Comment: @ModusTollens Exactly.

Comment: @user49915, my point is that it depends on the community. If you ask a proper question for the community, I have not seen a problem. As for giving a reason for a down vote, votes are anonymous, and that would defeat anonymity. If you hover your mouse pointer over the down arrow, it gives you the default reasons: "_This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful_." That is what you must assume, but anybody is free to anonymously vote for whatever reason.

Comment: @user49915 Ok, I didn't get that from the question. I thought it was meant for specific Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: @ModusTollens I made it precise right now.